# https://r-forge.r-project.org/ and packages from it are not working

Tags: r, package, r-forge

I wrote a script with a package from r-forge. yesterday I tried to use it again but I had a problem with installing this package. The following message appeared:

```
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘IsolationForest’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
cannot open URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

I also checked the web-page https://r-forge.r-project.org/ and it is not working at all. Does anyone found an Information explaining if there are some maintenance works or something like this? Checked also on other computers.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mail received on June 4 2018:

> Dear r-forge users,
>
> We would like to remind you, that r-forge will be unavailable
>   presumably from Jun 5th to Jun 7th due to major maintenance works.
>
> Best regards, R-Forge team.

Answer (score 1):

Today (June 26 2019) attempts from our university (York University in Toronto, Canada) to access anything within domain r-project.org fails. I checked with a colleague at Purdue and he had no problem, suggesting there may be something amiss locally or in whatever DNS servers we go to.

Result from Brave browser:

> This site can’t be reached www.r-project.org’s server IP address could
>   not be found. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS
>   configuration ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> from within R:
>       `x=available.packages()` Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
>   'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
>
> within R, explicit repository named:
>       `install.packages('txtplot',repos="http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/")`
>   Installing package into
>   ‘/home/clement/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) trying URL
>   'http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/src/contrib/txtplot_1.0-3.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 6152 bytes
>
> from Ubuntu:
>       `sudo apt-get update` Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease Hit:2
>   http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/server/POWER/Linux/xl-compiler/eval/ppc64le/ubuntu
>   trusty InRelease                  Hit:3
>   http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
>   Hit:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
>   Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
>   Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fkrull/deadsnakes/ubuntu xenial
>   InRelease Hit:7
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial
>   InRelease Err:8 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
>   InRelease   Could not resolve host: cloud.r-project.org Err:9
>   https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/ InRelease 
>   Could not resolve host: cloud.r-project.org Err:10
>   https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease 
>   Could not resolve host: cloud.r-project.org Reading package lists...
>   Done W: Failed to fetch
>   https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial/InRelease  Could
>   not resolve host: cloud.r-project.org W: Failed to fetch
>   https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial-cran35/InRelease 
>   Could not resolve host: cloud.r-project.org W: Failed to fetch
>   https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/InRelease 
>   Could not resolve host: cloud.r-project.org W: Some index files failed
>   to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
>
> Henryk's problem was resolved by the message from phiver that R-forge
>   would be down for maintenance in early June. It's not clear to me that
>   our problem is the same? Is there a place other than r-project.org to
>   check for scheduled maintenance of the site?

Comment: double checked on twitter: other R users reporting same problem